# What does "story run" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm looking for a proper definition of the phrase "story run". I found the phrase in the Runastic app and then came across on the website called A Christmas Story Run. But I still can't get what it means. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Link? Quote of sentence?

Comment: Hello, Karolina. The alternative 'Christmas Story House Run' given at the Cleveland [Three Dog Bakery ... event/ ...](https://threedogbakerycle.com/event/christmas-story-house-run/) website indicates that 'story run' isn't composite. This is like asking "What does 'Country run' mean?" when you come across 'Penshurst Village Cross Country Run'.

Comment: Karolina, a 'story run' is a new term, [made up by Runtastic](https://www.runtastic.com/blog/en/pushing-the-limit-interval-training/) and possibly other exercise apps, that is intended to mean a run that follows a story or works like a story. Grammatically it is using 'story' as a [noun attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). But as others note, the pair can also occur with 'story' being part of a larger noun-phrase ('a Christmas story') again used as a... well... noun- _phrase_ attribute (modifying the following 'run'). Also, note, 'run' is used in all these examples as a noun